# Passing Data to Modal Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

URL in a class HTML i want to pass That to an anchor tag inside another button inside a modal. But I have no idea about it.

Example - This hyper link `<a class="sent" href="<?phpecho $row->play; ?>"> </a>` need to pass this hyper link `<a href=""><button>Click Here</button></a>`

Below is similar code that passes the data to the iframe.. I tried that way but I couldn't do it.

```
<iframe class="iframe"  width="235px" height="290px" ><video src="" type="video/mp4" /></iframe> 
<a class="modalclick" href="<?php echo $row->play; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row->cover; ?>" alt="...">



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modalclick').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
    
  });
  //auto close or pause on model hide
  $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", '');
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't think a link would be the best way to do that. Although you may use "data-*" attributes to assign a value to this link and then use that on the link to hem the expected modal.

Comment: I have no idea about it. Do you have any examples?

Comment: according to your comment to the mistaken answer that I posted, you want to pass the url to a button inside the modal. What you need to do is to create the html of the modal and then set that property on that button. code the modal and post it here so I will be able to help you.